# What's going on with my LAN?

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, fedora

I'm writing today because I'm having a problem with my LAN I can't seem to figure out. A few days ago my windows devices lost internet connectivity while my Unix based devices still connect. It's not a hardware fault because my main PC runs both windows 10 and fedora 32; the windows environment has no internet connection, but if I boot it into Fedora it does have internet connectivity. What's going on here?

Comment: I wonder if the DHCP service on your router has stopped working and if Windows boxes are not getting an IP while Linux boxes are failing g back to the lat known IP.  I would try reboot the router. If that doesn't fix the problem, please advise the IP address and gateways on the Linux and Windows systems (and maybe see if statically assigning an IP on a Windows system gets things going again?)

Answer (score 1):

#### What's going on here?

Please try a full reset of the Windows network stack.

Run the following commands in an elevated `cmd` shell:

- Reset WINSOCK entries to installation defaults (reboot required):

  `netsh winsock reset catalog`
- Reset TCP/IP stack to installation defaults:

  `netsh int ip reset reset.log`
- Reset Firewall to installation defaults:

  `netsh advfirewall reset`
- Flush DNS resolver cache:

  `ipconfig /flushdns`
- Renew DNS client registration and refresh DHCP leases:

  `ipconfig /registerdns`
- Flush routing table (reboot required):

  `route /f`

Comment: Okay, I tried that. Still unable to connect on either windows device.

Comment: Some devices (plural) can connect and some devices (plural) cannot connect to the same router. Do a hardware reset of the Router to factory specs, set it up again, and then restart all devices that connect to it. See if that works.

Comment: Manual IP or DHCP (auto) ?  try manual.  So old routers can get clogged up , so I agree on reset to router or is it VPN?

Comment: I did a hard reset on the router, set everything up and tried a static ip. Still nothing; I'm starting to think there's a hardware fault with the router itself.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the problem. If anyone else has this issue, make sure the time on your router is set the same as your PCs.